# Raising a value by one bit in c

Tags: c, bit

Let's say I have 46 in C, and I'd like to raise the value by 1 bit, to 47.

`101110` to `101111`

I have no clue how to use the bitwise operators in C. I'm sorry for such a simple question.

Comment: Why not use something like `int foo = 46; foo++;`?

Comment: So you want to avoid `foo++`, `++foo`, `foo += 1` or `foo = foo + 1`, and only use bitwise operators to increase a specific value/variable by one?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are working with ints, you only need to do:

```
int myint = 46;
myint++;
```

Comment: @MikeHenke don't feel dumb, there's holes in everyone's knowledge, that's why we're always learning.

Answer (score 2):

Well as stated before the easiest way is just increment by one your variable lets imagine something like this:

```
int main()
{
  int x=46;
  x=x+1; // You could also use x++, ++x 
}
```

But because you specifically asked for bit wise operations then it should look like this:

```
int main()
{
  int x=46;
  x=x|1; 
}
```

The explanation is very simple basically is like this:

When you assign a variable it's represented as bytes in the stack area of the program so 46 for example can be represented as 00 00 00 2E, you can of course step down a little and see it as a group of bits, so 46 becomes  00000000 00000000 00000000 00101110.

When you use a bit wise operation like "x=x|1;" you are basically asking the computer to assign the variable "x" with the result of the former value of "x" and an or operation with a number one so ...

00000000 00000000 00000000 00101110

00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001

becomes

00000000 00000000 00000000 00101111.

Note the last bit is one, that's because 0 or 1 always is evaluated as one.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Just pointing out that `x=x+1` and `x=x|1` are not the same thing: the latter only adds one because 46 is even.

Answer (score 1):

Incrementing it by one bit is equivalent to additional by one. So you can just do

```
x + 1
```

You'll have to watch out for overflow as usual.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do increment using bit operations -

1. from the left side change all the 1 to 0 until first 0 is encountered
2. Change the left most 0 to 1.

Eg. 1 : 46 - 10111**0** - since first bit is 0 -> change to 1 => 101111 which is = 47

Eg. 2 : 23 - 10**111** - convert 1s  to 0s until first 0 is encountered -> 1**0**000 - convert left most 0 to 1 => 11000 which is = 24

```
public  int increment(int num)
{
  int x = 1;

  /* change all the bits to 0 which are 1 from the left side */
  while( (num & x) !=0)
  {
      num = num^x;
      x <<= 1;
  }

  /* change the rightmost 0 bit to 1 */
  num = num^x;
  return num;
}
```

I hope this helps.